# Flask redirect(url_for) with arguments

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to building web apps using Flask and having trouble using `redirect(url_for)`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

def getSomeList(paramsFromHTML):
    return someList

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        myData = getSomeList(paramsFromHTML)
        return redirect(url_for("show_data", this_data=myData))
    else:
        # Show the default page for GET requests
        return render_template("welcome.html")

@app.route("/show_data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_data(this_data):
    return render_template("show_data.html", data=this_data)
```

Once I get some details from HTML in my main index page, I need to route it to the `show_data` view function.
The function has a parameter (this_data). However, there is no parameter in the route itself - like `"/show_data/<string:something>"` It is just `"/show_data"`

I get the below error when trying this.
`TypeError: show_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'this_data'`

Is it mandatory to have some kind of a parameter in the url route as well?
Is there any work around I can try for my use case?

Comment: Just adding a note that there were similar questions and looks like the parameter in the url route might be necessary for this to work. But didn't find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working after removing the args part (this_data) from my show_data function and use the below to get the value -
`this_data = request.args.get('data')`